# how to dubug the looping chain in synonym?

Tags: oracle

i have this script, when i execute this script it shows the Error Messge like,

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01775: looping chain of synonyms
01775. 00000 - "looping chain of synonyms"
```

what can i do?

```
DROP TABLE ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE;
CREATE TABLE ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE
(
  ID                      NUMBER,
  WFM_ID                  NUMBER,
  EXECUTION_DATE_PLANNED  DATE,
  EXECUTION_DATE_ACTUAL   DATE,
  STATUS                  VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE_PK ON ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE
(ID);

DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE FOR WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE;

ALTER TABLE ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE ADD (
  CONSTRAINT WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE_PK
 PRIMARY KEY
 (ID)  USING INDEX );


GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON  ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE TO ENT_OWNER_SELECT_ROLE;

GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON  ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE TO ENT_OWNER_UPDATE_ROLE;

GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON  ENT_OWNER.WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE TO ENT_USER;
```

Answer (score 4):

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE FOR **ENT_OWNER.**WF_REPORT_JOBQUEUE;